# how to find distance between 2 points on google map?

Tags: asp.net

I want to calculate the distance between 2 points in Google Maps. I have the latitude & longitude of both points but want the distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Haversine formula.

Check out the DistanceTo() function on the following page:

http://blog.codebrain.co.uk/post/2009/05/08/C-Distance-Between-Two-Postcodes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

for this  you should have use following codes.
for Design

```
    function OrginAutoComplete() {
        try {
            var input = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.setTypes('changetype-geocode');
        }
        catch (err) {

        }
    }


    function DestAutoComplete() {
        try {
            var input = document.getElementById('TextBox4');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.setTypes('changetype-geocode');
        }
        catch (err) {

        }
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', OrginAutoComplete);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', DestAutoComplete);
</script>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Pick Up address"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="DroppOff Address"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Details" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" style="margin-left: 55px" Width="97px" />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
```

For coding in c#:

string xmlResult = null;

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" + TextBox1.Text + "&destinations=" + TextBox4.Text + "&mode=car &language=us-en&sensor=false");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        StreamReader resStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();


        xmlResult = resStream.ReadToEnd();


        doc.LoadXml(xmlResult);

        string output = "";

        try
        {

            if (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/status").InnerText.ToString().ToUpper() != "OK")
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Invalid City Name please try again";
                return;
            }



            XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/DistanceMatrixResponse");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                if (xn["status"].InnerText.ToString() == "OK")
                {

                    output = "<table align='center' width='600' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
                    output += "<tr><td height='60' colspan='2' align='center'><b>Travel Details</b></td>";
                    output += "<tr><td height='40' width='30%' align='left'>Orgin Place</td><td align='left'>" + xn["origin_address"].InnerText.ToString() + "</td></tr>";
                    output += "<tr><td height='40' align='left'>Destination Place</td><td align='left'>" + xn["destination_address"].InnerText.ToString() + "</td></tr>";

                    output += "<tr><td height='40' align='left'>Distance</td><td align='left'>" + doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text").InnerText + "</td></tr>";
                    output += "</table>";



                    lblResult.Text = output;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error during processing";
            return;
        }



    }



    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double cost = 0;
        double distance = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox5.Text);
        if (distance >= 50)
        {
            cost = distance * 0.4;
            lblResult.Text = cost.ToString();
        }
       else if (distance >= 1000)
        {
            cost = distance * 0.35+50;
            lblResult.Text = cost.ToString();
        }
        else   if (distance < 50)
        {
            cost = distance * 0.65;
            lblResult.Text = cost.ToString();
        }
        else  if (distance <=10)
        {
            cost = distance * 0.85;
            lblResult.Text = cost.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search revealed [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).
There you can do calculations and it also explains the formulas used.
I'd start by looking at the Haversine folmula.